# c++ special variable name

Tags: c++, visual-c++, variables

When I create variable I just put the a name for it, but can I create the name of the variable like this:

```
int var+1= 1;
```

So basically that should be:

```
int var1=1;
```

I know I can't use the + sign to do that but is there way to do it?

---

EDIT

```
int g=1;
string hello+g = "sdljfsdl"; // So hello+g will be hello1
```

So it is like mixing variable value by another variable value to get new variable name.

Comment: What you want *exactly* is not possible with C++.  You can use arrays or `std::map` or something of that nature to mimic what you are asking for.

Comment: How are you going to refer to 'hello+g' after you've initialized the variable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this with macros, but you really shouldn't need dynamic variable names.  It sounds like this sort of problem can be solved with an array:

```
int vars[5];

vars[0] = 3;
vars[1] = 4; 
// etc.
```

Comment: @Ramiz: why can't you use arrays?

Answer (score 6):

It is unlikely to be desirable, but you could use token pasting in the preprocessor:

```
#define PASTER(x, y) x ## y
#define EVALUATOR(x, y) PASTER(x, y)

int EVALUATOR(var, 1) = 1;
```

Comment: "unlikely to be desirable" is an understatement.  Aren't there enough C Macros in the world?

Comment: @Merlyn: there are far too many macros - nevertheless, this one would more or less achieve the desired result, though the name is so long that it overwhelms the basic variable name.  Which is another argument against using it.

Comment: @Johnathan: That's why you'd name it something short.  And get rid of the *shift* because that's harder to type: `#define w(x, y) x ## y` ... `#define k(x, y) w(x, y)` ... `int k(var, 1) = 1;`.  Or even better, name it after some function you never use, like realloc...

Comment: @Merlyn: you need the twin macro dance in general, so that given `#define M1 var` and `#define M2 1`, you can write `EVALUATOR(M1, M2)` and get the result `var1` rather than `M1M2`.  As to length of name, then yes, you can shorten it.  It doesn't make the idiom any better, but it can be shortened.

Comment: Sorry, my deadpan is a little too deadpan today :)  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you almost certainly need [`std::map`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(C%2B%2B)), or, if available, [`unordered_map`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unordered_map_(C%2B%2B)). both will allow you to construct keys however you like and set/get values for those keys e.g.

```
std::map<string,int mymap;
string fixed = "fixed part";
string var = " 1"; //or construct this from a number
mymap[fixed+var] = 3; //fixed+var == "fixed part 1"
```